# Options on Android for real time sending of data to a server?

Tags: android, networking, real-time

I am currently working on a small scale project to prove something works, I currently have a smart band device which has an Android SDK.

From this device I use the SDK to track a users heart rate in real time.

So my Android application receives updates to the heart rate in real time.

This was fairly easy to do however I now need to send this data in real time from the Android device to the server as efficiently as possible.

To start with battery drain is OK as initially this is just a proof of concept.

I have limited experience with sending large amounts of data to a server in real time and I was wondering if anyone has an ideas on what might be the best approach on Android?

I have looked into Sync Adapters but these seem to be more about keeping data aligned between the client and the server, this is something I am not concerned about. Another approach would be to see if the RequestQueue from Volley might work but again I am unsure if looking into this is even worthwhile?

Should I be looking into creating a Service and somehow using a socket to transfer the data?

EDIT: It looks like IntentService may be the best option for handling the task execution but I am assuming http requests would be too heavy for the client and I should look into something else for the transfer?

Comment: Have you tried one of real time services like Pubnub,quickblox and parse?

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks, some of those services look excellent and I will look into them at some stage but right now I need to do this without using a software service.

Comment: Welcome @donal i recommend you to look at Pubnub first i have used it in many real time app and it was great

Comment: As i understand you want to implement real time feature by your hand?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the best practices for sending real time data from Android to a server.

Comment: That's great, your question is on my favorite list and i'm looking for answers :)

Answer (score 4):

I am working on similar kind of project but the wrist band I am dealing with is Empatica E4. Please bear in mind that I am not an expert developer, therefore I am also looking forward for corrections in my design. Also, I will try to justify my idea step-by-step and as much as I can. I hope that this will give you some hints for your application and help others as well.


 So, my current architecture looks like;

 
[image: System Architecture]

First of all, Empatica has also provided an Android SDK to receive the data. SF stands for Sampling Frequency whereas EDA, Temp, BVP and AccXYZ are my sensors in wrist band. Each sensor has different sampling frequency and the maximum is 64 Hz which gives you 15 ms interval between each samples. This interval is quite challenging to perform all the operations, therefore I buffer the sensors data in (Volatile [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)) FIFO queue so that I don't miss any sample. This was all happening in the service of my application.

 Now, I have a Runnable task that I have used with [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to collects samples from the queue with the interval of 250 ms (you can vary it as per your need but I used 250 ms considering my needs, network latency and the device performance) and put them in a single JSON object. Number of samples that this Runnable task collects are varying for each sensor, which are, BVP: 16 samples, AccXYZ: 8 samples, Temp: 1 sample and EDA: 1 sample. At the output, I have a JSON object with the data to be sent to my server.

 
 For transferring data to my server, I am using HTTP POST request. The reasons are easy, fast, efficient and good for concurrency. I am using [Volley framework](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) which will handle all my network related issues by itself. So I just add the JSON object in the Volley RequestQueue and my client is done here. As you mentioned, you can use socket connection to achieve your goal but I have to use multiple devices, therefore in my case, sockets can be problematic to achieve concurrency. I also tried to do it manually by using HttpURLConnection but the code was becoming tedious and hard to handle. 

 
 Finally, I have a REST API (in Python) on my server side which will handle the POST requests, parse the data and insert it in my MySQL database. As of now, I am still working on this REST API to parse the data and store it in DB. However, I have tested my application and I am successfully receiving the data from my device to the server.

Regarding your question "Should I be looking into creating a Service and somehow using a socket to transfer the data?", it's an excellent option if you are working on a single device. If more than one device, i think Http is better option.

Regarding your second question, I don't think Http would be heavy for the client and Volley is taking all your pain on itself. You just have to make a request queue and voila !!! You can find plenty of good tutorials for volley and I particularly followed [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-volley-example/).

I hope my answer will help you a little.

**PS:** As I am still working on this thing and I have not come up with the final product yet, therefore I cannot surely tell about the risks involved in it but I will keep you updated if something new happens. Also, I am open to any suggestions and ideas that can help. Lastly, the picture above is not very detailed, I made it for you, just to share how I am dealing with the same idea.